# Mongodb custom authorization function

Tags: mongodb, authorization

My goal is to intercept each call to MongoDB, check of incoming data if access to this resource instance is allowed or if updates to this specific resource instance are allowed, etc. Good would be an interceptor which can inspect incoming and outgoing traffic with the context information of the executing user. Is this possible with MongoDB? I have found only  a way to add [custom authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/authentication/custom-function/) which is not what I need. Are there proxies which can be used for this?

Comment: This should be done by [roles and grants](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/authorization/) Don't try to re-invent the wheel!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit But roles are not fine grained enough. I need the access decision based on resource instance level.

Comment: Roles go down up to collection level. What do you mean by "resource instance"?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit With resource instance I mean if have a collection "foo" and there are stored 2 documents "foo with ID 1" and "foo with ID 2". Both documents should get independent authorization checks. In addition these checks have to be dynamic, i.e. if a user is accessing the document it depends on some other time limited token to get the access, the permission is not fixed.

Comment: I think the must be implemented on application level.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I was assuming this, but I wanted to check before if there are any other options.

Comment: [Field redaction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/implement-field-level-redaction/#implement-field-level-redaction) isn't exactly what you are looking for, but that doc might get you on the right track